# can't show a stimulsoft report more than 1 time

Tags: report, stimulsoft

I've created a simple report in vs.net 2008 with stimulsoft report 2013.
I'm using these codes to show report:

```
    StiReport1.RegData(ds)
    StiReport1.Render()
    StiReport1.Show()
```

when I click on the button **I Can see the report correctly** for the first time.
but when i close the reportviewer's Windows and click on that button again the 
report is empty (I can see the header or footer but no data loaded on the report)
I think the report data not load again or something saved on cache.
please Help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED
Try this code. its work for me

```
StiReport1.Dictionary.DataStore.Clear();
StiReport1.Dictionary.Databases.Clear();
StiReport1.Dictionary.DataSources.Clear();
StiReport1.BusinessObjectsStore.Clear();

StiReport1.RegData(ds)
StiReport1.Dictionary.Synchronize();
StiReport1.Compile();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
StiReport1.ResetRenderedState();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved.
I should just save the report and load it each time:

```
    Dim rpt As Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport = New Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport
    rpt.Load("report/MyReport.mrt")
    rpt.RegData(ds)
    rpt.Render()
    rpt.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your Viewer before rendering. Use ResetReport() function before Reg and Render codes.